# How can I track progress of dd

Tags: macos, command-line

I am using the following command to create a bootable SD Card

```
sudo dd bs=4m if=en_windows_10_enterprise_version_1511_x64_dvd_7224901.iso of=/dev/disk2
```

Is there a way to track the progress?

Comment: [How to get dd to print transfer stats in MacOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772392/how-to-get-dd-to-print-transfer-stats-in-macos)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The same information, displayed every second by in [klanomath's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234167/how-can-i-track-progress-of-dd/234173#234173), can displayed using your command. You just need to enter a <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> character from the keyboard while the `dd` command is executing.

By pressing the <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> character, you are sending the same `SIGINFO` signal to the `dd` command that the command `pkill -INFO -x dd` sends.

Comment: Worked like a charm! So much easier (and less hair-raising) than the other methods

Comment: wow!!!! that's great!

Comment: in a separate terminal:
`while true; do pkill -INFO -x dd; done`

Answer (score 61):

As of coreutils 8.24, dd added a status options.  Install coreutils with Homebrew to update dd.

```
brew install coreutils
# All commands have been installed with the prefix 'g'
sudo gdd if=XXXX.iso of=/dev/diskX bs=1 status=progress 

> example:
> 139648967 bytes (140 MB, 133 MiB) copied, 304 s, 459 kB/s
```

Comment: Didn't know about coreutils, very handy.

Comment: Although this works, you nullify the speed increase of using the [Raw Disk](http://serenity.ee/post/82120938429/mac-os-dd-with-devdisk-vs-devrdisk)

Comment: You can still use raw disk as follows: `sudo gdd if=XXXX.iso of=/dev/rdiskX bs=1M ` and check progress via `CTRL` + `T`

Comment: @eyoung100: How? If I point my `if...` and/or `of...` options directly at the raw version/s, does coreutils' `dd` ignore this and use the buffered version/s anyway? This seems completely nonsensical to me, which makes me question the source of your beliefs (especially since your link is now dead).

Answer (score 26):

You can press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> while the `dd` command is running or for a nice progress bar you can install `pv` (pipe viewer) via Homebrew:

```
brew install pv
```

and then execute:

```
sudo dd if=disk-image.img | pv | sudo dd of=/dev/disk2
```

or (knowing size of the image, 16GB in this example):

```
dd if=disk-image.img | pv -s 16G | dd of=/dev/disk2
```

**Example output 2:**

(data transferred, elapsed time, speed, progress bar and estimated time):

```
    1.61GiB 0:12:19 [2.82MiB/s] [===>                 ] 10% ETA 1:50:25
```

Comment: The best answer is the one without added dependencies.

Comment: While adding `status=progress` to `dd` is handy, I prefer this method because it gives you a progress bar which, for a long transfer, is handy to see progress at a glance.

Answer (score 14):

`dd` itself doesn't provide a progress bar. You may estimate the progress of the dd copy process by adding a *pkill -INFO* command though.

Example:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=64m count=1000 & while pkill -INFO -x dd; do sleep 1; done
```

Result:

```
[1] 37691
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.028923 secs (0 bytes/sec)
275+0 records in
275+0 records out
18454937600 bytes transferred in 1.029698 secs (17922667819 bytes/sec)
553+0 records in
553+0 records out
37111201792 bytes transferred in 2.048291 secs (18118129881 bytes/sec)
829+0 records in
829+0 records out
55633248256 bytes transferred in 3.068911 secs (18128009214 bytes/sec)
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
67108864000 bytes transferred in 3.720346 secs (18038339571 bytes/sec)
[1]+  Done                    dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=64m count=1000
```

Which translates to a whopping 18.1 GB/s.

Comment: What are the hardware specs of the machine you ran that command on?

Comment: @user3439894 3.5 GHz i7 iMac. Why?

Comment: Was just curious because of the bytes/sec output, which by the way is actually 16.8 GB/s (rounded-up) as those are base 2, not base 10 calculations.

Comment: @user3439894 the very high speed in this example is because `dd` copies between the zero and null devices. The speed measures how fast the kernel can generate zeros and then throw them away. When used to zero a drive this'll obviously be bottlenecked by the drive's write performance.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, install [Homebrew Package Manager](https://brew.sh/). Then you have to install `pv` and `dialog` with this command:

```
brew install pv dialog
```

You can then run this command to get a progress bar with the command:

```
dd if=disk.img bs=1m | pv disk.img | dd of=/dev/diskX bs=1m
```

but make sure to replace `disk.img` with the path to the image and `diskX` with your SD card's disk identifier. If you want something more graphical, you can try this:

```
(dd if=disk.img bs=1m | pv -n disk.img | dd of=/dev/diskX bs=1m conv=notrunc,noerror) 2>&1 | dialog --gauge "Writing image to SD card..." 10 70 0
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/516724/765767

Answer (score 5):

`progress` can track progress of data transfer processes. Install with

```
brew install progress
```

Then launch `dd`, get its PID with

```
ps aux | grep "dd"
```

and use the tool to track progress

```
sudo progress -mp 95413
```

Comment: Does this work with the standard `dd` on macOS or only with the GNU coreutils version?

Comment: It works with standard dd, I didn’t install GNU coreutils.

Comment: Super thanks, It worked like a charm

Comment: @enpi Glad to help you!!!

Answer (score 4):

That is easy!   For macOS High Sierra and below, just run a while loop and it will run until it is finished.   Just make sure to do the code below in another window:

The code below will work out of box while in a firmware boot or within the full blown OS

```
while kill -0 $PID; do
    caffeinate -t 10 
    kill -INFO $PID
    echo "still copying file" "$(date)"
done
```

^ To keep the machine awake (caffeinate) without the use of “homebrew” or tools not available in standard Mac OS X since homebrew requires internet and an actual OS to install it on.

**NOTE:** The above needs you to substitute the PID with your process ID and it will constantly show the progress

Comment: To find the actual PID run command:
    `pgrep -l '^dd$'`