# Could not validate sizes – Operation not permitted. The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1.)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, catalina, restore, bootable-disk

I am following instructions for creating a Bootable drive (generously provided in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe/389830#389830) by a gentleman named David Anderson). I am using a 16GB SD card to try to create a Bootable drive from my MacBook running Catalina.

The instructions could be simplified by doing a Restore using the Disk Utility to the external drive (SD card or flash drive), with `BaseSystem.dmg` being the restore source.

The problem is that when I try this, I get the following error (also see screenshot)

> Could not validate sizes – Operation not permitted. The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1.)

What does this mean? Is there a better way to fix this than the one given in David Anderson's answer. Or, can the `asr` command be made to work reliably, so the Disk Utility would not have to be used?

[image: disk-utility-mac-could-not-validate-sizes]

Comment: Are you attempting to create a *bootable installer* of Catalina or simply a USB flash with Catalina installed on it?

Comment: A bootable installer

Comment: Ok..so you also said "...from my MacBook running Catalina."  Why not just download the installer and use `createinstallmedia` per Apple's instructions?  This seems like a rather roundabout way to accomplish this.

Comment: @Allan: I edited the question. My answer, that the OP was referring to, involved an El Capitan installer.

Answer (score 25):

I think the "Operation is not permitted" may be caused by Disk Utility lacking the necessary admin privileges.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/asr restore --source BaseSystem.dmg --target /Volumes/MyVolume --erase
```

Should do the trick (terms and conditions apply)

Comment: This is what worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This worked! I also had to open Disk Utility and prepare the source image via Images > Scan for restore...

Comment: I had to put quotes around the source and target parameters for this to work, e.g. `--source "BaseSystem.dmg"`

Comment: This worked for me in attempting to re-install Mac OS X Lion (previously bought in App Store) on an old Macbook. Benign error messages:
```Checksum failed.
Expected 7425D663
but got 84E748B9
Could not restore - Invalid argument```

Comment: This almost worked for me. It did not succeed doing it straight from the DMG though. I had to mount the DMG and use the mounted directory as the source.

Comment: I got exactly the same error as @LloydDewolf

Comment: I got the same error but had NO TROUBLE using the memory stick to re-install Lion.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it easily using ASR command

- You have to scan your downloaded image via following command

  ```
  sudo /usr/sbin/asr imagescan --source ~/Downloads/macOSUpdCombo10.15.7.dmg
  ```
- After scan you have to run following coammand to restore the image into the USB.

  ```
  sudo /usr/sbin/asr restore --source <IMAGE_PATH> --target /Volumes/<VOLUME_NAME> --erase
  ```

If there is any issue, please share in here.

Comment: I found that before imagescan would run I had to convert the source image to read-only using the image Convert command in Disk Utility.

Comment: The above solution didn't work because imagescan was needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, to be clear, you are doing this from macOS Recovery or while you are booted up on the bootable USB installer right? Also, a 16GB SD card is not enough to hold macOS Catalina. If you are looking to make an SD card that has a ready installation of macOS Catalina, then you can download the Install macOS Catalina app and then use that to install on the SD card (again, the amount of storage isn't enough). https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac.

If you are experiencing issues with creating a bootable installer, then I think your best option would be to download the Install macOS Catalina app from the App Store and then use the `creatinstallmedia` command to create the installer. See the link for more https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372.

Comment: I edited the question. My answer, that the OP was referring to, involved an El Capitan installer. AFAIK, there has been no mention by the OP or me of installing Catalina on a SD card.

Comment: @DavidAnderson The question was unclear so I provided instructions for both.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to Terminal you can:

1. list your disks

   `diskutil list to get your SD_CARD_NAME`
2. unmount your SD card

   `diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/SD_CARD_NAME`
3. erase it with the desired file system (AFS or JHFS+)

   `diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Emptied /dev/SD_CARD_NAME`

Then go ahead with your restore