# Bootable pendrive takes lot of time during 'Copying installer files to disk...'

Tags: macos, catalina, startup, bootable-disk

I am creating bootable pendrive with MacOS_ELCapitan using Macbook Pro 2019(Cataline).

using https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388508 this thread.

But i am getting `Copying installer files to disk...` i have waited 4 hours for this.

### **Attached screenshot**

[image]
Attached screenshot

Comment: Have you tried a different thumb drive? Also there is a free utility that also does this https://diskmakerx.com, perhaps that will give you different results.

Comment: Thanks Steve.. It was due to slow pendrive.