# 2014 MBP No More Operating System / Boot usb not Detected

Tags: macos, startup, install

I have a mid-2014 MBP that I tried to downgrade but unfortunately ended up wiping out everything in the hard disk.

Once it restarted, it doesn’t startup anymore and only the long press on [Option] after turning on is accessible. I have tried [Command + R], [Command+Option+Shift+R]… but it doesn’t work.

So On the only accessible menu I’ve found so far, I have access to {Internet Recovery} but it seems not working because I connected to the internet and waited 4 hours but nothing happened.

I considered using a usb boot but it doesn’t show up as an option, even though my other USB with no OS in it is detected by the Mac Startup Manager and displays a {windows} icon.

The USB is certainly not damaged since it’s recognized correctly when it doesn’t have the dmg installer.

Could somebody please help?

Comment: By "dmg installer", are you referring to the a file named `InstallOS.dmg` or `InstallMacOSX.dmg`? Do you have any other Macs available?

Comment: That’s a MacOS 10.15 dmg burnt on a flash drive with TransMac. Yes, I have access to a M1 MacBook Air

Comment: Where did you get the MacOS 10.15 dmg? I ask because I am unaware of any such dmg that can be downloaded from Apple or from the App Store.

Comment: It was from a different source than Apple because I didn’t have access to another Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible answer would be to first install El Capitan, then upgrade to Catalina. The procedure is outlined below.

1. Use the M1 Mac to download the El Capitan `dmg` file from the Apple website ["How to get old versions of macOS"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683).
2. Use the M1 Mac to create a El Capitan USB flash drive installer. See the question: ["How do I create El Capitan installer on a Catalina (or post-El Capitan) installed Mac for use on USB boot installer?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe).
3. Use the flash drive to erase the disk on the 2014 MBP, then install El Capitan.
4. Apply all updates to the installed El Capitan.
5. Use the link provided on the Apple website ["How to get old versions of macOS"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) to download Catalina from the App Store. If not available, then try to download to an older version of macOS such as High Sierra.
6. Use the `Install macOS Catalina` application to upgrade to Catalina. If you downloaded an older version of macOS, then upgrade to the older version, then download and upgrade to Catalina.

### Other References

- [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400)
- [Create a bootable USB drive from a DMG file on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/383235/create-a-bootable-usb-drive-from-a-dmg-file-on-windows)

Comment: Thank you very much. I’ll try this solution.

Comment: I have tried your solution and it worked. Thank you very much.
I have used the VMware Fusion Solution.