# Was trying to upgrade an El Capitan iMac, deleted entire HD in setup process... How do I make a bootable USB of Capitan on my High Sierra Mac?

Tags: macos, imac, usb, bootable-disk

The title says it all... I've tried several guides off Google .. There's no recovery on the iMac that had El Capitan... I have another iMac with High Sierra, so I how do I make a bootable El Capitan USB within High Sierra?

I have tried creating a bootable disk on transmac with no luck.

Every time I've tried to use the `creatbootabledisk` command on my High Sierra Mac, it throws an error and I have the files named the proper named according to which guide I'm following.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. When you write `creatbootabledisk`, do you mean `createinstallmedia` instead? Could you add the error message to your question (please don't add a screenshot of the error message but copy the text and then paste it to your question)?

Comment: What Mac model and what version of OS X (macOS) were you trying to upgrade to? Your question basically states you had El Capitan and were trying to upgrade to El Capitan. This in my mind make little sense. What model is the Mac with High Sierra installed? Can you provide a link to which guide you were following? Can you provide a link to where you found the El Capitan you downloaded from Apple (or possibly some other source)?

Comment: I am not sure if this question should be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe), or for needing details or clarity.

Comment: As others already said: please add more details about the commands you run and the output you got, ideally by copy/paste from Terminal *as text*.