# Download BigSur for bootable flash drive

Tags: macos, install

Yesterday, I updated an old MacbookAir6,2 to macOS 11.7.3. Unfortunately, it did not start after this update and recovery (`command + R`) does not work, since I can't connect to any network. So I wanted to download BigSur and create a bootable device. AppStore does not work, since my Macbook runs macOS 13 and it won't let me download 11.7.3.

`softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 11.7.3` does also not work since `softwareupdate --list-full-installers` only shows available versions from `12.6.1` to `13.2`. How can I download `11.7.3` (or any other compatible version for a MacbookAir6,2) to create a bootable flash drive?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Comment: I am aware of that link. However, the links for macOS newer then 10.12 would guide me to the AppStore from where I cannot download it (see above). So is 10.12 the only option I have?

Comment: Besides that I can't install (extract) Sierra on my Mac since it won't let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the canonical QA [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos). In addition, I have included two methods which are suited to your situation.

---

### Method 1

Download an available version from 12.6.1 to 13.2 to the host Mac. Install the chosen version in a virtual machine guest on the host. Oracle and VMware offer free software. Boot from the virtual machine guest and use the command below to list available downloads.

```
softwareupdate --list-full-installers
```

> Note: Guests can list more versions of macOS installers than the host can. Hosts will only shown macOS versions compatible with the host. Guests do not have this restriction.

From the guest, use the `softwareupdate` command to download an available installer application which is compatible with your MacbookAir6,2. Transfer the application to the host Mac. Follow the instructions given at Apple's website  [Create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) to create the bootable USB flash drive installer.

---

### Method 2

Use of of the answer from the question [How do I create El Capitan installer on a Catalina (or post-El Capitan) installed Mac for use on USB boot installer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe) to create a Sierra, El Capitan or Yosemite USB installer.

By using this method to get back to Big Sur, you would have to update your Mac. Recently, I have noticed that the Big Sur downloads from the App Store do not necessarily include all the software needed to install Big Sur. These types of downloads can not be used to create a USB flash drive Big Sur installer. So while this method may get you back to Big Sur, you may not be able to create a USB Big Sur installer by using this method until your MacbookAir6,2 is actually booted to Big Sur.

Comment: Thanks for all these answers. I have to say installing a VM to get a bootable flash drive sounds like an overkill to me. That's really a shame that it's that complicated to get my old Mac running again. Due to the lack of time I gave up now and just bought an bootable BigSur drive on ebay.

Comment: Apple would not expect you to use my answer. Apple would expect you to use Internet Recovery from the MacbookAir6,2. In your case, I assume you do not have WiFi or the other Mac can not access the internet though a hardwired ethernet connection.

Comment: Internet recovery is not working. When I start with `(option +) command + R`, I'll reach the WiFi selection and after entering the password it just loads forever. Reset NVRAM, PRAM, SMC with `command + option + P + R` and `shift + control + option + power` don't solve this. I have a mac compatible Ethernet adapter, but this also has no effect with the "bricked" Air 6.2.