# Creating a bootable usb of High Sierra on MacOS Monterey

Tags: macos, usb

I'm trying to bring back my old 2010 Mac Mini back from the dead. For various reasons, Internet Recovery doesn't work on it, so I need to create a bootable USB.

I've got the full installer for High Sierra on my daily driver (14in Macbook Air M2) but the darn thing won't open with a message like 'this version of MacOS is too old for this Mac...' similarly, trying to run the High Sierra createinstallmedia command in Terminal just results in terminal `killed` output.

What's the solution to create a bootable USB for an older version of MacOS on a modern/current Mac?

Comment: See if this helps:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/119271  If it doesn’t come back and explain what went wrong

Comment: A High Sierra installer is intel-only.  Do you have Rosetta installed if you are trying to use `createinstallmedia` from it?

Comment: A lot of the "How to build *OSX* on *Mac Y* guides no longer work as written, because the installers have changed format in recent years.

Comment: I tried just running `createinstallmedia` from HS on an M1Pro with Monterey.  The crash report says: "  "reportNotes" : [
  "_dyld_process_info_create failed with 6",
  "dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed",
  "Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\\_(ツ)_\/¯"
]"

Comment: (cont) That shruggie is in the crash report.

Comment: Dan: You could try creating an USB flash drive El Capitan or Sierra installer on your M2 Mac, then use to install on your 2010 Mac. Once you have the 2010 running, you should be able to access the Apple Store to get High Sierra or use the High Sierra you downloaded to your M2 Mac.

Comment: Instructions for creating an El Capitan installer can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe/389830#389830). While the same instructions can be adapted for Sierra, you might want to use [these instructions](https://maclinks.publicvm.com/bootablesierra.html) instead.

Comment: @MarcWilson I've tried it both on Apple Silicon and Intel and the installer is just to old to run / too told to run `createsinstallmedia`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It turns out **you can't** use `createinstallmedia` on a newer Mac than the installer is designed for; you need to manually create a bootable USB stick [using the instructions here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe/389830#389830). It's appears a bit convoluted but is ultimately straight-forward. Bear in mind some of the terminal commands are dependent on your USB transfer speed so don't worry if some just appear to hang.

It's also worth noting that whilst I was trying to get MacOS High Sierra, I ended up getting the installer for Sierra [from this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos) as the download gave me a real file and not an annoying and ultimately useless App Store link.