# How do I clone an installation of Windows 10 from macOS?

Tags: windows, ssd, ntfs

I have an external SSD which has a working copy of Windows 10 on it. I would like to transfer this copy of Windows 10 onto a different SSD. However, I do not currently have access to a Windows computer.

How would I clone this installation of Windows onto the new SSD? I already have Paragon NTFS installed, which allows me to write to NTFS drives. What should my next step be?

1. I could drag and drop everything from the Finder into the new SSD. However, this might not copy over some hidden files and might not be a good option.
2. I could drag and drop after revealing hidden files, but that might also cause issues (?)
3. I could use rcopy to make sure everything gets copied over (including hidden files), although I don't see any difference between this and option 2.

Note: This question is not necessarily related to BootCamp—I would like to know the same for M1 Macs as well, which do not have BootCamp.

Comment: You cannot do 1., 2., or 3. and end up with a working copy of the **OS**!

Comment: Is there any reason why? I presume it's also similar on macOS due to the existence of specialized software that makes bootable clones, but I don't see why it wouldn't work if you copied all the files over. Maybe I'll make a new question about that.

Comment: Even back in the **DOS** days, just copying the files from one drive to another didn't give one a working copy of **DOS** and while it was easy to do so after the copy it's nowhere near the same for **Windows 10**. If you want a working bootable system then you need to use appropriate software to image/clone the disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `dd` command to clone the disk as follows:

1. If the **source SDD is larger than the destination SSD**, start up your Mac in Windows 10 and shrink the partition on the source disk, as explained in this Microsoft document: [Shrink a basic volume](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/shrink-a-basic-volume), so that its size is smaller than the destination SSD. Then restart your Mac in macOS.
2. Connect both SSD disks to your Mac

   If you get a message similar to this when connecting the destination disk:

   [image]

   select "Ignore".
3. Launch Disk Utility (located in the Applications > Utilities folder).
4. Select the **source disk** and write down the device name.

   In the screenshot below, the device name is `disk2`:
   [image]
5. Select the **destination disk** and write down the device name:

   In the screenshot below, the device name is `disk3`:
   [image]
6. Select the **source volume** and unmount it.
   [image]
7. Select the **destination volume** and unmount it. (**This step will not be necessary if were prompted to select "Ignore" in step 1.**)
   [image]
8. Launch Terminal (located in the Applications > Utilities folder).
9. Run:

   `sudo dd if=/dev/rdiskX of=/dev/rdiskY bs=1m`

   where:

   `diskX` is the device name of the source disk (in the example above, `disk2`). Note the `r` in `/dev/rdiskX`: we use the *raw* device file for a faster copy.

   `diskY` is the device name of the destination disk (in the example above, `disk3`). Note the `r` in `/dev/rdiskY`: we use the *raw* device file for a faster copy.

   `sudo` is a command that lets you run the `dd` with administrative privileges.

   Type your password if requested.

   ***It is extremely important that you don't mix up the device names of the disks! Otherwise you will overwrite your Windows 10 disk.***

   This may take a while, so be patient. You can check the progress of `dd` as explained in this answer: [How can I track progress of dd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234167/how-can-i-track-progress-of-dd)
10. Test the destination SSD. You may want to extend the volume as explained in this Microsoft document: [Extend a basic volume](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/extend-a-basic-volume)

### More information

For more information on `dd`, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)

For more information on `sudo`, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

For a very similar but command line-only method to clone disks in macOS using `dd`, see: https://pbxbook.com/other/dd_clone.html

Comment: Very good work!  Learned a lot of new things today!  Many Thanks jaume

Comment: dd is extremely slow on Mac, not useful

Comment: @Tom You may want to try `sudo dd if=/dev/rdiskX of=/dev/rdiskY bs=1m`. It's still `dd`, but notice the `r`: now `dd` reads and writes the _raw_ device files, which skips the cache and may increase speed. YMMV.

Comment: That is much faster, but still way below SATA speed.